# Typescript - generic return type based on the type of the property of object union

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Suppose we have a following type:

```js
type Config = {
    key: "literal_one",
    value: number,
} | {
    key: "literal_two",
    value: string,
}

export type ConfigKey = Config["key"];
// "literal_one"|"literal_two"
```

How can we implement the following function?

```js
function getConfig(key: ConfigKey) /* : different return type based on key*/ {
    const conf: Config = this.repository.getById (key);
    return conf.value;
}
```

When I am assigning an object to a variable with the Config type, Typescript definitely knows that it is impossible to set string value when the key is `literal_one`. And marks this as an error.

```js
const conf: Config = {
    key: "literal_one",
    value: "not number" // Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
};
```

So, I assume it should be possible to get the particular `value` type of the `Config` object and use it as a return value of the function.

How can we force the `getConfig` function to have a return type based on the given `ConfigKey`? Maybe using some kind of generics... (I mean not a `number|string` return type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Extract` here:

```
function getConfig<K extends ConfigKey>(key: K): Extract<Config, { key: K }>["value"] {
  // ...
}
```

We'll extract all members of `Config` that are assignable to `{ key: K }`, then get the value type of those members.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmUC8UDeAoKQqAawhAC4oAiAGxWAgCcBDGgfUQioBoCiA3VgFcIlBEIC2AIya8AvlAA+uPoVIVqdBi3bAA7nB6qogmiMoBnYIxQI08vHggAPMHEbAooSLESo0ANJkWL7I6ADaVOpUALoA3HgA9Ima9EysHAhcirRpOmz6ho4AJhAAxjTMjNBIQghlwCiIUGgQwPBhaAA8AVAuDAjFFqH+QSAAfAAU6pQBAJSUAKLO1swNXR3+3LgkZLNQcuORpiKxCXhliFZQnCGt7X7ok7naGZxUcwnJRFAAegD8FyunkKdzamyeL3SugMHy+KSIALwQA)

Comment: Tnank you, this is a great answer! At the declaration level Typescript now knows needed typings! But when I try to write the function's body, I got a monstrous error. Please, look at the sandbox below. Do you have ideas why TS shows this error?

Comment: Sandbox: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmUC8UDeAoKQqAawhAC4oAiAGxWAgCcBDGgfUQioBoCiA3VgFcIlBEIC2AIya8AvlAA+uPoVIVqdBi3bAA7nB6qogmiMoBnYIxQI08vHlCRYiVGgDSZLK+ToA2lTqVAC6ANx4APSRmvRMrBwIXIq0cTps+oaOSEIIAMbAKIhQaBDA8H5oADweUBAAHgwIACYWvu5eIAB8ABTqlB4AlJQAoo0sBVUV7ty4JGQDUHJdgaYioSpEUIxlQowI8yBYmNip2gmcVFAA-FAAjADMD1CUVFaMVBFyjnmIVlCcHylcpudA9M7xdiXQYRaJbAB61zwvwQ-0yQLK0zBEPSmSoMKiMSIiLwQA

Comment: @JamesBond You might have to use a cast or even ignore it. I expected an error like this. I should've included that in the answer and playground.

Comment: Now I just cast the return value to any: `return (key === "literal_one" ? 133 : "str" as any)`. This crutch seems working: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmUC8UDeAoKQqAawhAC4oAiAGxWAgCcBDGgfUQioBoCiA3VgFcIlBEIC2AIya8AvlAA+uPoVIVqdBi3bAA7nB6qogmiMoBnYIxQI08vHlCRYiVGgDSZLK+ToA2lTqVAC6ANx4APSRmvRMrBwIXIq0cTps+oaOSEIIAMbAKIhQaBDA8H5oADweUBAAHgwIACYWvu5eIAB8ABTqlB4AlJQAoo0sBVUV7ty4JGQDUHJdgaYioSpEUIxlQowIUH3emCex2gmcVFAA-FAAjADMD1CUVFaMVINQzG3MCCAROSOPKIKxQTg+UrlNzoHqpc7sS6DCLRLYAPWueBBCDBmUhZWmsPh8V0Bk+KJiRAxeCAA

Comment: I suppose that `any` could work but ideally it would be `Extract<...>[...]`. If it works well enough for you, that's fine I guess.